# SOQL query log for oauth-connected application

Tags: soql, api, logging

Is there a log/audit trail of API calls made by an oauth-connected application? I've found some logging inside the Salesforce developer console, but it seems to only apply to APEX code. Any idea how I can see the API calls in my org? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the feature, you can use [Event Monitoring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm) to see all of the API calls in your org, but this is a paid feature. You can use this feature to dig up all of the actions an API has performed.

You can also get a log for all API calls that create a log (e.g. Execute Anonymous, Test runs, and so on) in the Developer Console. These are filtered out by default; you need to click on Debug and unchecking Show My Current Logs Only.

Comment: I was able to pull a log of REST API events. It was missing the actual SOQL statements and parameters (any idea if those are stored anywhere?), but it was still very helpful. Thanks!